# how to access the elements of a list that is a pandas object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a listof characters (seqMut2) which is a series pandas object in dataframe, I try to browse this list as a normal list to retrieve the position of elements that are not spaces with this code:

```py
    index2 = chDeux[chDeux['allele'] == y].index.values
    index3 = chTrois[chTrois['allele'] == x].index.values
    list_chDeux = [chDeux.loc[index2, 'chaincode'], chDeux.loc[index2, 'allele'],chDeux.loc[index2, 'sequencegaps'], chDeux.loc[index2, 'sequencegapsalidiff']]
    list_chTrois = [chTrois.loc[index3, 'chaincode'], chTrois.loc[index3, 'allele'],chTrois.loc[index3, 'sequencegaps'], chTrois.loc[index3, 'sequencegapsalidiff']]
    seqG2 = list_chDeux[2].str.split(pat='')
    seqG3 = list_chTrois[2].str.split(pat='')
    seqMut2 = list_chDeux[3].str.split(pat='')
    seqMut3 = list_chTrois[3].str.split(pat='')
    
    for i in seqMut2 :
     if j != " " :  
      print(j)          
      pos=seqMut2.index(j)
      print(pos)
```

but with `print(j)`, I see that it retrieves the whole list, so when I try with a normal list (manually without dataframe) I get the right result:

```py
seq="   M  M" 
list=seq.tolist()
 for j in list : 
   if j != " ":  
     print(j)   
     pos=list.index(j)  
     print(pos)
```

result: j = M and pos = 3

j = M and pos = 5

Comment: You need to provide us a minimal sample (to reproduce the problem), and the expected output (to provide a solution)

Comment: I have a column in my pandas array of type serie.pandas which is a list of characters (or a space instead of a character) and I want to retrieve the position of the elements of the list which are characters and not spaces (as in the second code which works, it is a normal list without being an object of pandas array

Answer (score 0):

You can filter for the rows where the value is different from a space ' '

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('my name is')})

   a
0  m
1  y
2   
3  n
4  a
5  m
6  e
7   
8  i
9  s

# Get only the values that are not empty strings

print(df[df['a'].ne(' ')])

Output:
   a
0  m
1  y
3  n
4  a
5  m
6  e
8  i
9  s
```

Or, if there is variety of spaces, like 1/2/3, you can use str methods on pandas series, which yields the same result

```
print(df[df['a'].str.contains('\S+')])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works because at the end I have to get the position of the characters in the list with the right character (even if there are several "A" for example, each "A" has to have its position in the list. I put a part of my code that precedes the step of having the list

Answer (score 0):

You can use simpler method with a list comprehension and native Python Code :

```
result = [ch for ch in seq.split(" ") if ch != '']
```

If you have more special characters then you can also add more filters afterwards

UPDATE :

to get the elements' positions if you have one or several elements besides your elements:

```
elements = [a for a in seq.split(" ") if a != '']
positions = [seq.split(" ").index(el) for el in elements]
```

Then you can create a dictionnary with the elements and the position :

```
dict_pos = {el:pos for (el,pos) in zip(elements, positions)}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works because at the end I have to get the position of the characters in the list with the right character (even if there are several "A" for example, each "A" has to have its position in the list. I put a part of my code that precedes the step of having the list

Comment: Not harder, you can check my update and say if it answers your problem

Comment: I have this as an error: 
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
the items in my list is just one character. 
You can look at my code update to understand better.

The problem is that in my for loop it doesn't return element by element (i.e. character by character) but it returns the list itself

Comment: You've got to show an example of an input otherwise it's not clear